# The SQL query is working, but it returns an empty result

Tags: sql

I need to write an SQL query for a case, but at the end of my query, I can't see my data.

The case is this

```
The process of handling development requests from business units is carried out on the system. Each request goes through the following stages before being completed.
Stage 1 - Manager Approval: Approval by the employee's manager who initiated the request.
Stage 2 - Analysis: Conducting analysis work and completing the analysis document.
Stage 3 - Analysis Approval: Sending the analysis document for approval to the request owner.
Stage 4 - Development: Development work.
Stage 5 - Testing: Testing work.
Stage 6 - Completed: Records that have completed the testing phase wait in the Completed stage.

The IT team wishes to measure the average completion time for a request. The time spent by the record in the IT department will start after "Manager Approval" is granted, and the time spent during the "Analysis Approval" stage will not be included in the IT duration. A report in the following format regarding business unit times is requested:


Month         | Average Days (Monthly) | Average Days (Yearly) |
March 2019    |                        |                       |
January 2019  |                        |                       |
February 2019 |                        |                       |


MONTH: Represents the month in which the request was closed. For January 2019, the average values of requests completed in January 2019 will be displayed.
AVERAGE DAYS (MONTHLY): The average completion time of requests completed in the respective month.
AVERAGE DAYS (YEARLY): The average completion time of requests completed from the beginning of the year until the end of the respective month.
```

I did this but I got empty table as a result.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        request_id,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(start, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') AS start_time,
        LEAD(TO_TIMESTAMP(start, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI')) OVER (PARTITION BY request_id ORDER BY TO_TIMESTAMP(start, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI')) AS next_start_time
    FROM mytable
    WHERE stage = 'MANAGER_APPROVAL'
)
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', start_time), 'Mon YYYY') AS "Month",
    ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_start_time - start_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Monthly)",
    ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_start_time - start_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC * 12, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Yearly)"
FROM CTE
WHERE next_start_time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY "Month"
ORDER BY "Month";
```

Here is some sample rows from my table.

```
id  request_id     stage           start              finish
1   5052047    MANAGER_APPROVAL 1/2/19 11:45    1/2/19 12:11
2   5052047       ANALYSIS      1/2/19 12:11    1/10/19 20:00
3   5052047   ANALYSIS_APPROVAL 1/10/19 20:00   1/11/19 8:57
4   5052047       ANALYSIS      1/11/19 8:57    1/11/19 9:17
5   5052047   ANALYSIS_APPROVAL 1/11/19 9:17    1/15/19 10:50
6   5052047   DEVELOPMENT       1/15/19 10:50   2/4/19 12:21
7   5052047        TEST         2/4/19 12:21    2/11/19 10:48
8   5052047     COMPLETED       2/11/19 10:48   NULL
```

Comment: `WITH CTE AS(SELECT request_id, start::timestamp AS manager_approval_start_time, LEAD(start::timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY request_id ORDER BY start::timestamp) AS next_stage_start_time FROM mytable )SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', manager_approval_start_time),'Mon YYYY') AS "Month", ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_stage_start_time - manager_approval_start_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Monthly)", ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM next_stage_start_time - manager_approval_start_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC * 12, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Yearly)" FROM CTE GROUP BY "Month"`

Comment: When you do to_timestamp it has to be with time zone so I casted to timestamp with `:: `. Plus I removed the where conditions. 
Is it working well Can I suggest this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        request_id,
        start::timestamp AS manager_approval_start_time,
        LEAD(start::timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY request_id ORDER BY start::timestamp) AS next_stage_start_time
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', manager_approval_start_time), 'YYYY-MM') AS "Month", 
TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', manager_approval_start_time), 'MON-YY') AS "Month1", 
    ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_stage_start_time - manager_approval_start_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Monthly)",
    ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_stage_start_time - manager_approval_start_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC * 12, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Yearly)"
FROM CTE GROUP BY "Month", "Month1" ORDER BY "Month";
```

Second query

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        request_id,
        start::timestamp AS manager_approval_start_time,
        LEAD(start::timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY request_id ORDER BY start::timestamp) AS next_stage_start_time
    FROM mytable
)
, MonthlyAverages AS (
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', manager_approval_start_time), 'Mon YY') AS "Month",
        TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', manager_approval_start_time), 'YYYY-MM') AS "Year-Month",
        ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_stage_start_time - manager_approval_start_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Monthly)"
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY "Month", "Year-Month"
)
SELECT
    "Month",
    "Year-Month",
    "Average IT Duration (Monthly)",
    ROUND(AVG("Average IT Duration (Monthly)") OVER (ORDER BY "Year-Month") , 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Yearly)"
FROM MonthlyAverages
ORDER BY "Year-Month";
```

Comment: `WITH CTE AS(SELECT request_id,start::timestamp AS manager_app_time,LEAD(start::timestamp)OVER(PARTITION BY request_id ORDER BY start::timestamp) AS next_stage_start_time FROM mytable)SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', manager_app_time), 'YYYY-MM') AS "Month", ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_stage_start_time - manager_app_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Monthly)", ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (next_stage_start_time - manager_app_time)) / 86400)::NUMERIC * 12, 2) AS "Average IT Duration (Yearly)" FROM CTE GROUP BY "Month" ORDER BY "Month";` Try this @BahadırÇolak

Comment: @BahadırÇolak, check out the second query in the answer. I am not sure if that is want you wanted...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255600/discussion-between-senthil-p-nathan-and-bahadir-colak).